# Mathematica on Command Line: graphics errors under Mojave

Tags: graphics, mac-os-x, command-line

Running Math 11 (or earlier) under Mac Mojave (10.14.5) from the command line, as soon as I display graphics I get a series of errors that look like this:

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.200.3/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8

Seems to run fine nevertheless, but what are these errors?  How to fix / suppress them?

Comment: Please give precise instructions on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I assume it is enough to start the kernel in command line mode and evaluate `UsingFrontEnd[1]`?  I've seen this with macOS 10.13 as well. I did not notice ill effects, but I do not know what causes it. Did you ever try to apply file system compression to Mathematica?

Comment: To reproduce the problem, open the math kernel on the command line in Terminal under Mojave and then execute, for example,  Plot[x^2,{x,-1,1}].  The math kernel is the executable /Applications/Mathematica*/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel.  Yes, executing UsingFrontEnd[1]
gives the same errors.  The problem started after upgrading to Mojave (no change was made to my Mathematica installation).